# replace values in a data.frame with values from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different dimensions,

```
df1 <- data.frame(names= sample(LETTERS[1:10]), duration=sample(0:100, 10))

>df1
   names duration
1      J       97
2      G       57
3      H       53
4      A       23
5      E      100
6      D       90
7      C       73
8      F       60
9      B       37
10     I       67

df2 <- data.frame(names= LETTERS[1:5], names_new=letters[1:5])

> df2
  names names_new
1     A         a
2     B         b
3     C         c
4     D         d
5     E         e
```

I want to replace in `df1` the values that match `df1$names` and `df2$names` but using the `df2$names_new`. My desired output would be:

```
> df1
   names duration
1      J       97
2      G       57
3      H       53
4      a       23
5      e      100
6      d       90
7      c       73
8      F       60
9      b       37
10     I       67
```

This is the code I'm using but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it with no so many steps,

```
df2[,1] <- as.character(df2[,1])
df2[,2] <- as.character(df2[,2])
df1[,1] <- as.character(df1[,1])    

match(df1[,1], df2[,1]) -> id
which(!is.na(id)==TRUE) -> idx
id[!is.na(id)] -> id

df1[idx,1] <- df2[id,2]
```

Many thanks

Comment: You should set the seed to have a reproducible example.(`set.seed(1)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach from [qdapTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html):

```
library(qdapTools)
df1$names <- df1$names %lc+% df2
```

The `%l+%` is a binary operator version of `lookup`. The left are the `terms` and the right side is the lookup table.  The `+` means that any noncomparables will revert back to the original.  This is a wrapper for the [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) package and is pretty speedy.

Here is the output including `set.seed(1)` for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(names= sample(LETTERS[1:10]), duration=sample(0:100, 10),stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(names= LETTERS[1:5], names_new=letters[1:5],stringsAsFactors=F)

library(qdapTools)
df1$names <- df1$names %lc+% df2

df1

##    names duration
## 1      c       20
## 2      d       17
## 3      e       68
## 4      G       37
## 5      b       74
## 6      H       47
## 7      I       98
## 8      F       93
## 9      J       35
## 10     a       71
```

Comment: Extremely slick and fast solution!

Answer (score 2):

Are all names in `df2` also in `df1`? And do you intent to keep them as a factor? If so, you might find this solution helpful.

```
idx <- match(levels(df2$names), levels(df1$names))
levels(df1$names)[idx] <- levels(df2$names_new)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but requires that `names` and `names_new` are character and not factor.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(names= sample(LETTERS[1:10]), duration=sample(0:100, 10),stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(names= LETTERS[1:5], names_new=letters[1:5],stringsAsFactors=F)


rownames(df1) <- df1$names
df1[df2$name,]$names <- df2$names_new
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `merge`:

```
transform(merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE),
          names=ifelse(is.na(names_new),as.character(names),
                                        as.character(names_new)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `match` would be (if `df1$names` and `df1$names` are characters of course)

```
df1[match(df2$names, df1$names), "names"] <- df2$names_new
```